# Why does the last bit of an Elixir bitstring default to 1?

Tags: binary, elixir, bitstring

Create a bitstring of 3 bits:

```
b = <<1 :: 3>>
```

Use bitstring comprehension to show the value of each bit:

```
for <<x :: 1 <- b>>, do: inspect x
```

Output:

```
["0", "0", "1"]
```

Notice that the last bit is 1, not 0.

How come all bits are not 0 by default, and can that be achieved somehow?

Comment: Eh. `b = <<0 :: 3>>`? Whether you want the value to be zero, just set it to zero.

Comment: Oh, good lord. I'm such a moron; total brain fart. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, it happens to all of us :)

Comment: Just to keep things neat and tidy; if you add your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code

```rb
b = <<1 :: 3>>
```

effectively sets a bitstring of length 3 bits to the value `1 (≡ 001)`. To initialize the bitstring to have all bits set to zero, use:

```rb
b = <<0 :: 3>>
```

Check:

```rb
b = <<0 :: 3>>
for <<x :: 1 <- b>>, do: inspect x
#⇒ ["0", "0", "0"]
```

*Sidenote:* e. g. `b = <<3 :: 3>>` will result in bitwise representation of `3 ≡ 011` etc.